# chart.js formatting, split x axis in half, and y axes have different datasets that correspond to each other

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

I'd like find a way to have `Dataset 1` on the left side y axis, as well as make it so the axis doesn't overlap with the values of the right side y axis. Essentially I'd like to split the chart in half and have one side represent one dataset and the other y axis represent the other dataset. The two datasets correspond, so they align horizontally.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>TEST</title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "garamond";
      }
      .chartMenu {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 40px;
        background: #006600;
        color: #ffffff;
      }
      .chartMenu p {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
      }
      .chartCard {
        width: 100vw;
        height: calc(100vh - 40px);
        background: rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        
      }
      .chartBox {
        width: 700px;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        border: solid 3px rgba(54, 162, 235, 1);
        background: white;
        
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="chartMenu">
      <h1>Chart</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="chartCard">
      <div class="chartBox">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    // setup 
    const data = {
      labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        data: [3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2],
        backgroundColor: [
          "#006600"
        ],
        borderColor: [
          '#006600'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
    {label: 'Dataset 2',
  data: [1,1,1,1,1,1],
backgroundColor: ['#001100']}]
    };

    // config 
    const config = {
      type: 'bar',
      data,
      options: {
        indexAxis: 'y', // <-- MAKES CHART HBAR
        scales: {
          y: {position:"bottom",
            beginAtZero: true
          },
          y2: {position:"top",
            beginAtZero: true,
            
          },
          x: {position:"left",
            beginAtZero: true,
            reverse:true
            
          },
          x2: {position:"right"
        
        
        }//, type:"linear", display: false} // display:fales makes right axis invisible







        }
      }
    };

    // render init block
    const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('myChart'),
      config
    );

    // Instantly assign Chart.js version
    const chartVersion = document.getElementById('chartVersion');
    chartVersion.innerText = Chart.version;
    </script>
    

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think the description of what you want to achieve is clear enough. Consider including in your post an image of the desired result.